# what is javascript const class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am learning Redux&React from http://teropa.info/blog/2015/09/10/full-stack-redux-tutorial.html.

In a code code snippets:

```
import React from 'react';
import PureRenderMixin from 'react-addons-pure-render-mixin';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import Winner from './Winner';
import Vote from './Vote';

export const Voting = React.createClass({
  mixins: [PureRenderMixin],
  render: function() {
    return <div>
      {this.props.winner ?
        <Winner ref="winner" winner={this.props.winner} /> :
        <Vote {...this.props} />}
    </div>;
  }
});

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    pair: state.getIn(['vote', 'pair']),
    winner: state.get('winner')
  };
}

export const VotingContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(Voting);
```

The author is creating "wired" react component from "pure" component. I am a bit confused with two "const" key words shown in the code. I can understand const value and object in javascript, but const class does not make sense to me from an OO perspective.

Will it make any difference if I remove "const" keyword from first and/or second cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Const is a block scoped assignment that assigns a constant reference (not constant value.) This means that you cant reassign Voting or VotingContainer later on by accident within that module.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

(and yes you could switch out const with let/var)

Comment: I will just point out that const's behaviour is inconsistent between strict mode and normal javascript. Choosing to use const should really only be done when using the execution environment directive "use strict" as on Chrome at least consts violate block scope when not in strict mode. This could be changed at any time, causing undetected bugs to suddenly appear,

Comment: @Blindman67 So does this mean that the behavior is quite unpredictable especially if I expect it to run in different browser? Will simply remove "const" and code carefully resolve the problem?

Comment: If you use it correctly you should be ok, in strict mode these errors will throw, while in normal javascript they will fail silently, allowing a bug to exist without detection until the browsers change the rules..Rather than not use const, ensure all code is running in strict mode with the `"use strict"` directive. The benefits of strict mode are great, better syntax error detection, faster code, and peace of mind that your environment is not going to suddenly change. Really if you are not using "use strict" you are playing with fire.

Comment: This example assumes you're using an ES6 transpiler. It has ES6 modules. Babel will turn `const` into `var`.